# How to automatically TRIGGER python to do some script when my Google sheet is updated?

Tags: python, triggers, google-sheets-api

I saw hell a lot of videos where we can trigger python every 10min or a specific day BUT
I cant find how to trigger python to do something when my sheet is updated, pls provide a SIMPLE solution

(*I am using my personnel pc NOT cloud service)
thx in advance

help me please thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

To automatically trigger a Python script when your Google Sheet is updated, you can use the Google Sheets API along with a webhook service. Here's a step-by-step guide to achieving this:

1. Set up the Google Sheets API:

   - Go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
   - Create a new project or select an existing project.
   - Enable the Google Sheets API for your project.
   - Create credentials (OAuth 2.0 client ID) for your project.
2. Install necessary packages:

   - Install the `gspread` package by running `pip install gspread`.
   - Install the `oauth2client` package by running `pip install oauth2client`.
   - Install the `google-auth` package by running `pip install google-auth`.
3. Create a Python script:

   ```py
   import gspread
   from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
   import json
   import requests

   def main():
       # Replace 'path_to_credentials_file' with the actual path to your JSON credentials file.
       scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
       credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path_to_credentials_file', scope)
       client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

       # Replace 'your_spreadsheet_id' with the actual ID of your Google Sheet.
       sheet = client.open_by_key('your_spreadsheet_id').sheet1

       # Define the range to monitor for changes, e.g., 'A1:C10'
       range_to_monitor = 'A1:C10'

       # Get the current values in the range
       current_values = sheet.range(range_to_monitor)

       # Continuously check for changes in the range
       while True:
           # Get the latest values
           latest_values = sheet.range(range_to_monitor)

           # Compare the latest values with the current values
           if latest_values != current_values:
               # Values have changed, perform your desired actions here

               # Replace 'your_webhook_url' with the URL of your webhook service
               webhook_url = 'your_webhook_url'
               payload = {
                   'values': [cell.value for cell in latest_values],
               }
               headers = {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               }
               response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

               # Update the current values to the latest values
               current_values = latest_values

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```
4. Create a webhook service:

   - Create a webhook service or API endpoint that can receive the request from the Python script. You can use frameworks like Flask or Django to create the service.
   - Implement the necessary logic in the webhook service to handle the received data from the Python script.
5. Set up the trigger:

   - Use a third-party service like Zapier or IFTTT to set up a trigger that listens for changes in your Google Sheet.
   - Configure the trigger to send an HTTP request to your webhook service whenever the Google Sheet is updated.

By following these steps, you can automatically trigger your Python script and perform actions whenever your Google Sheet is updated.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).